# How can I tunnel a ssh command over an http url

Tags: shell-script, webserver, http, tunneling

I have to execute bash scripts over an http url. For example I have two serverS in the same network:

- From server A i want to send this http url:
  10.10.10.5/start.sh
- And in Server B is a the script "start.sh" located and should be executed. Also php sctipts should be executed in the same way.

How can I do that? Which webserver should I use?

Comment: Are you trying to visit http://10.10.10.5/start.sh via a browser on server A? I assume both servers are on the same network and can route to each other? If the answer to both is yes, then I'm not sure a tunnel is required; you could just call the url from server A directly.

Comment: If you do require a tunnel however, then you could do this from server A:

`ssh user@server_B.com -L 80:10.10.10.5:80`

then run this from server A: 

`curl http://localhost/start.sh`

Comment: So.. serverB is hosting the script, but you want to execute it remotely via serverA? Or what? Your question is very unclear.